# Javascript: this reference to variable name inside function?

Tags: object, window, this, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to get a reference to the variable name inside the variable, like

```
var foo = function(){
    alert(this);
}
var bar = foo();
```

It alerts [object window] instead of foo.

My **main reason** is that setInterval when used twice on the same variable makes the first interval have an unknown id that is non-clearable, as in clearInterval only clears the last one set and leaves the first one running. So I'd like to do something like:

```
var call_interval = setInterval;
setInterval = function(){
    clearInterval(this.name???);
    call_interval.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

... all in hopes of creating a setInterval that clears any existing intervals with the same variable, to prevent non-clearable intervals.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The parameter to `setInterval` is a function, not a variable. The thing you pass to `clearInterval` is the id returned by `setinterval`, not a name. You can pass the same function to `setInterval` twice, and you get two ids, and you can cancel them both of them by passing the ids to `clearInterval`. Maybe if you describe how you intend to use the modified `setInterval` function.

Comment: If you call setInterval again with the same variable like:
var foo = setInterval(function(){alert("foo");},1000);
foo = setInterval(function(){alert("bar");},1000);
The first interval becomes unreachable by clearInterval and continues to run.

Comment: Well, yeah, because you overwrote the variable. if you don't want to lose the old value, don't replace it with the new value. For example, you could do `intervals.push(setInterval(function(){alert("foo");},1000); intervals.push(setInterval(function(){alert("bar");},1000);` and now the two IDs are in the `intervals` array for independent clearing. Alternatively, you could create a `singleInterval` object with a `setInterval` method that automatically clears the old interval before setting the new one. But changing the way the language works is not the way to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's a clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As titled, this should answer your question, although as @Raymond Chen indicated, your actual problem may be different.

Per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), when invoked from outside of any function, `this` refers to the global object (in browser Javascript, this is the window).

When invoked from inside a function, if that function is a method of an object, `this` will be set to the object.

So in your case:

```
var x = {
  foo: function() {
    alert(this);
  }
};

var bar = x.foo();
```

However, this would still not tell you *which* function was called.

In order to get the name of the function, give your function an explicit name, and then use `arguments.callee` instead of `this` to parse out the name.

```
var foofunc = function foo() {
  var name = arguments.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1]);
  alert(name);
}

var bar = foofunc();
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want the function name. The OP wants the name of the variable that the return value of `setInterval` was assigned to. This is simply not possible. (And even if it were possible, it wouldn't help, because the return value may have been assigned into a local variable [which is therefore inaccessible from the global object], or it may never have been assigned to a variable at all!)